# Is Ye Shiwen's 400m IM performance in Olympics "anomalous" statistically?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, outliers, biostatistics, methodology

The 16-year-old Chinese swimmer Ye Shiwen swam more than 5 seconds faster than her personal best in women's 400m individual medley in London 2012 Olympics, winning her a gold. Her performance received high exposure to media and mixed comments, even some controversy. For example, Nature published a news report titled "[Why great Olympic feats raise suspicions -- 'Performance profiling' could help to dispel doubts](http://www.nature.com/news/why-great-olympic-feats-raise-suspicions-1.11109)" and immediately raised great attention and a great number of reader comments.

As an effort for myself to better
understand the issue and an exercise, I attempted a 'performance profiling' as what the
Nature news report's subtitle says.  What I did is to analyze the short-term
performance increase (or decrease) of top swimmers in 400m IM worldwide during 2011
and 2012, and try to see how Ye Shiwen compares to other good
performance improvers. I found there are more than 20 swimmers who are arguably better performance improvers than Ye. What's also worth noting is that Ye is at a particularly interesting spot that her performance is between the majority male and majority female swimmers. Probably not exactly a surprise given she's world's No. 1 in the event. See my summary: http://bit.ly/swimdata.
But I wonder if some of the critical eyes here can "cross validate" this approach.  What kind of factors should be examined in this kind of "performance profiling" for sports, and specifically for the Ye case?

Comment: For some context, look to other sports. Consider the [men's long jump world record progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_jump_world_record_progression), which is famous for the spectacular improvement in 1968. What you should conclude from this is that merely looking at improvements in records--whether individual or world--is probably not going to make a strong enough case. I suspect that a physical argument (based on the height-based thresholds for swimming speeds) might be more compelling.

Comment: I thought about performance improvement's possible dependency on swimmer physical characteristics (or the change of them). Unfortunately I can't find swimmers' height or weight, especially not two measurements in 2011 and 2012 respectively. Age was relatively easy to find so I analyzed the age dependency a little.

Comment: Height *really* matters. (There is a threshold speed proportional to the square root of length in the water, beyond which it takes much more additional energy to create faster speeds.)

Comment: Age may be important; you can improve a lot when you are young / still growing. Later in that same Olympics, the 800 meter winner, 15 year old Katie Ledecky, improved her personal best from 8:19.78 to 8:14.63 in less than a month, dropped more than 39 seconds over the past two years, and 15 seconds during the preceding six months.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katie_Ledecky   As I recall, the first 400 meters of her 800 meter run were faster than she swam her 400 meter race earlier!

Comment: @zbicyclist  I did do some [analysis on the age dependency](http://meng6.net/pages/project/Analysis_of_short-term_performance_improvement_of_top_swimmers_in_400m_individual_medley/#index3h3) although it only include a small number of 400m IM swimmers. I'd like to investigate other swimming events and see if age is the *key* factor. Thanks!

Comment: There is significant flexibility athletes have in optimizing their performances for particular events including training more and avoiding other competitions. For many, the Olympics represent the most important event, so many more are close to peak condition. In addition, as pointed out in the comment on the *Nature* article, athletes who are leading in races which are not close do not always go all-out. With stronger competition, top athletes have more reason to perform at record-breaking levels because they need to. Ye was trailing at the start of the apparently unusually fast last 100m.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 1968 games in Mexico City Bob Beamon shattered the world record in the long jump with a jump of 29 ft 2 inches topping a world record that was under 28 ft at the time.  It took decades for any one to come close and finally break Beamon's record.  What explains it?  The high altitude meant thin air and less air resistence.  Yet no one else went over 28 ft that day including Beamon on his other jumps.  No one suggested that Beamon took performance enhancing drugs.  It was a statistical outlier.  Outliers happen.  Statistical analysis won't explain it.  But in your case it seems that you have taken a very sensible and pragmatic approach.  You look at similar performers over the same time period for the same event and found many that improved their best times by more than what this chinese swimmer did.  I think that supports the view that her accomplishment is not very unusual and should not be attributed to any external reason such as some form of doping which is what I imagine some people may have been intimidating.

Comment: What is your answer to the question?  ("What kind of factors should be examined in this kind of "performance profiling" for sports, and specifically for the Ye case?")

Comment: @whuber I think my answer was given. I am saying that you compare her performance as measured by improvement over best time to others under conditions as similar as possible. If her result is extreme relative to the others than a flag (question) is raised.  If it is typical or at least not very extreme then nothing should be said.  My point about Beamon is that even in very extreme cases where the statistical evidence of miraculous performance improvement can be shown we may not want to conclude that anything improper took place.

Comment: Beamon is believed to have benefited from environmental conditions to some degree, including the maximum tail wind that won't disqualify the jump [see the bottom of this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Beamon#1968_Summer_Olympics) (still very impressive, of course).

Comment: @gung Yes there were minor factors that aided the jump but nothing that could really explain breaking a record (not even his own) by more than a foot.